# Wordpress Navigation Menu issues

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

How can i fix the navigation menu links in Wordpress,

> **I want to generate the menu in following format without using class or id references in child items.**

```
<ul >
            <li><a href="index.php">Home 01</a>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu A</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu B</a>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Menu 02</a>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu A</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu B</a>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
            </li>

</ul>
```

This is a Custom Menu and iam using widget to call it.

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Top Menus', 'my_custom_one' ),
        'id' => 'menu-widget-area-top',
        'description' => __( 'Top Menus', 'my_custom_one' ),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ) );
```

and I have used this PHP code in my template

```
$menu = 'menu-widget-area-top';
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => true, 
    'container_class' => ''.$menu.'', 
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => '', 
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => 0,
    'fallback_cb'     => false,
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '',
    //'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);
echo wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

Comment: you can do it using jquery, but you at least have to give id or class to parent elements, and then read child elements and show them below parent element

Comment: @Me-4U without using class or id ???? why ??

Comment: Why are you putting the menu items in DIVs? If they are not required I can create a wordpress function that will generate the menu without any extraneous classes and ids.

Comment: Hi, either with <div> or without <div> for child elements would do, i just want the structure to be very simple without any classes or ids assigned. Please share your function with me :)